# Openlayer - filter multiple layer (and multiple type (point + polygon)) by another layer

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to filter multiple layer (point and polygon) by another layer.

The idea is that the user select an area and every feature of every layer that doesn't intersect this area return an empty style (so each features get's hidden)

Currently my example work with intersectsCoordinates() **but doesn't work with polygon**.

Is there any method of intersect working for both point and polygon layer?

```js
//Base layer
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

//Point layer
var point =
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "https://wxs.ign.fr/geodesie/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=BDGEODESIQUE:triplet&outputformat=application/json",
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: (feature) => {
            return new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 8,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: "turquoise"
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'white',
                        width: 2
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })

//Areal layer
var polygon = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:commune&outputformat=application/json&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'pink',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});

// The map
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 8,
        center: [255000, 6266791]
    }),
    layers: [
        osm,
        point,
        polygon
    ]
});


let urlFilterLayer = "https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:departement&outputformat=application/json"

//filter layer
let filterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({})
});

//Ajout des couche de filtre après coup  
map.addLayer(filterLayer);

let filterLayerGeometry;


function filter() {
    // For each layer if it is outside the selected area, apply no style
    for (let myLayer of map.getLayers().getArray()) {
        if (myLayer.K != undefined) {
            for (let element of myLayer.getSource().getFeatures()) {
                if (filterLayerGeometry &&
                    filterLayerGeometry.intersectsCoordinate(
                        element.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
                    )
                ) {
                    element.setStyle(null)
                } else {
                    element.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({}))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


$('.radio').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($('#tous').is(':checked')) {
        // remove filter from area layer
        filterLayer.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        // For each layer (different from baselayer) reapply the default style
        for (let myLayer of map.getLayers().getArray()) {
            if (myLayer.K != undefined) {
                for (let element of myLayer.getSource().getFeatures()) {
                    element.setStyle(null)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        filterLayer.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_dep=" + $('input[name="dpt"]:checked').val(),
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        filterLayer.getSource().on('featuresloadend', function() {
            filterLayerGeometry = filterLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry();
            filter();
        });
    }

});
```

```html
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:600px;">
    
    
        <div id="radioIDFcontainer">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="tous" name="dpt" value="tous" checked>
            <label for="tous">All</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="75" name="dpt" value="75">
            <label for="75">Area 1</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="77" name="dpt" value="77">
            <label for="77">Area 2</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="78" name="dpt" value="78">
            <label for="78">Area 3</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="91" name="dpt" value="91">
            <label for="91">Area 4</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="92" name="dpt" value="92">
            <label for="92">Area 5</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="93" name="dpt" value="93">
            <label for="93">Area 6</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="94" name="dpt" value="94">
            <label for="94">Area 7</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="95" name="dpt" value="95">
            <label for="95">Area 8</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: OpenLayers doe not include a test for polygons intersecting, you would need to use a third party utility such as turf.js https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect  Before resorting to that you could check if one polygon intersects the the **extent** of the other one (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

I finaly managed to work with TURF.js

here is the solution :

```js
//Base layer
var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

//Point layer
var point =
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "https://wxs.ign.fr/geodesie/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=BDGEODESIQUE:triplet&outputformat=application/json",
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: (feature) => {
            return new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 8,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: "turquoise"
                    }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'white',
                        width: 2
                    })
                })
            })
        }
    })

//Areal layer
var polygon = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:commune&outputformat=application/json&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'pink',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});


// The map
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        zoom: 8,
        center: [255000, 6266791]
    }),
    layers: [
        osm,
        point,
        polygon
    ]
});


let urlFilterLayer = "https://wxs.ign.fr/administratif/geoportail/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&srsName=EPSG:3857&typenames=ADMINEXPRESS-COG-CARTO.LATEST:departement&outputformat=application/json"

//filter layer
let filterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({})
});

//Ajout des couche de filtre après coup  
map.addLayer(filterLayer);

let filterLayerCoord;
let dptGeometry;


function filter() {
    // For each layer if it is outside the selected area, apply no style
    for (let myLayer of map.getLayers().getArray()) {
        if (myLayer.K != undefined) {
            for (let element of myLayer.getSource().getFeatures()) {
                if(element.getGeometry().getCoordinates().length==2){
                //Case for points
                        if (dptGeometry && 
                            dptGeometry.intersectsCoordinate(
                                element.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
                            )
                        ){
                            element.setStyle(null)
                        }else {
                            element.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({}))
                        }
                }else{
                //Case for polygons
                    //Case for certain geometry type
                    if(element.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0].length==1){
                        if (filterLayerCoord &&
                        turf.intersect(turf.polygon(filterLayerCoord),turf.polygon(element.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0]))
                        ) {
                            element.setStyle(null)
                        } else {
                            element.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({}))
                        }
                    //Case for certain geometry type
                    }else{
                        if (filterLayerCoord &&
                        turf.intersect(turf.polygon(filterLayerCoord),turf.polygon(element.getGeometry().getCoordinates()))
                        ) {
                            element.setStyle(null)
                        } else {
                            element.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({}))
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


$('.radio').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($('#tous').is(':checked')) {
        // remove filter from area layer
        filterLayer.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_reg=11",
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        // For each layer (different from baselayer) reapply the default style
        for (let myLayer of map.getLayers().getArray()) {
            if (myLayer.K != undefined) {
                for (let element of myLayer.getSource().getFeatures()) {
                    element.setStyle(null)
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        filterLayer.setSource(
            new ol.source.Vector({
                url: urlFilterLayer + "&CQL_FILTER=insee_dep=" + $('input[name="dpt"]:checked').val(),
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            })
        );
        filterLayer.getSource().on('featuresloadend', function() {
            filterLayerCoord= filterLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
            dptGeometry = filterLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry();
            filter();
        });
    }

});
```

```html
 <head>
        <!-- OpenLayer -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/build/ol.js"></script>
        <!-- JQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- TURF -->
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:600px;">
    
    
        <div id="radioIDFcontainer">
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="tous" name="dpt" value="tous" checked>
            <label for="tous">All</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="75" name="dpt" value="75">
            <label for="75">Area 1</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="77" name="dpt" value="77">
            <label for="77">Area 2</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="78" name="dpt" value="78">
            <label for="78">Area 3</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="91" name="dpt" value="91">
            <label for="91">Area 4</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="92" name="dpt" value="92">
            <label for="92">Area 5</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="93" name="dpt" value="93">
            <label for="93">Area 6</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="94" name="dpt" value="94">
            <label for="94">Area 7</label>
            <input class="radio" type="radio" id="95" name="dpt" value="95">
            <label for="95">Area 8</label>
        </div>
```